# Editing Uniref FASTA header ID

Tags: sed, fasta

I'm trying to get the FASTA header of Uniref FASTA files to be in ”>ref|myid|seq definition” form. I know they are using sed command to work on it.

Header of the Uniref FASTA.

```
">UniRef100_Q6GZX4 Putative transcription factor 001R n=1 Tax=Frog virus 3 
(isolate Goorha) RepID=001R_FRG3G
MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVEWNNPPS
EKGLIVGHFSGIKYKGEKAQASEVDVNKMCCWVSKFKDAMRRYQGIQTCKIPGKVLSDLD"
```

To be as:

```
">UniRef100|Q6GZX4|Putative transcription factor 001R n=1 Tax=Frog virus 3
 (isolate Goorha) RepID=001R_FRG3G
MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVEWNNPPS
EKGLIVGHFSGIKYKGEKAQASEVDVNKMCCWVSKFKDAMRRYQGIQTCKIPGKVLSDLD"
```

Hope to get some clues on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed to replace first `_` by `|` and first whitespace by `|`:

```
sed 's/_/|/;s/ /|/' file > new_file
```

or this to edit file:

```
sed -i 's/_/|/;s/ /|/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something using perl:

```
cat your-fasta-file | perl -pe 's:^(.+?)_(.+?) :\1|\2|:'
```

What the regular expression which after the `'s:` does is find the smallest match from the beginning of the line up to the first underscore `^(.+?)_`
and then finds the smallest match up to the next space `(.+?)` and then it puts `|` after that first matched pattern `\1` and the second-matched pattern `\2`. The colons are what I use to delimit the pattern to search for and the pattern to replace with.